# byte[] to string without the null terminator

Tags: java, packet

So I'm getting a packet from the client on the server side and do the following

```
String Message = new String(receivePacket.getData());
```

However it gets the correct string without the null terminator...

Why does it happen and how can I solve that?

Comment: Java strings don't have null terminators.

Comment: I see the following in the debug window Message = (String) "Hello without the ending ", should I just add it using cat?

Comment: Why do you think you want a null terminator? Like I said, Java doesn't have them. Why do you think you need one?

Comment: When I do the following afterwords displayArea.append(Message); it just doesn't print right...

Comment: What is the type of displayArea?

Comment: JTextArea and I add it as new JScrollPane( displayArea ), it prints a lot of with spaces or something, like it doesn't has a closure.

Comment: In the Java programming language, unlike C, an array of char is not a String, and neither a String nor an array of char is terminated by '\u0000' (the NUL character). See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Java programming language](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.9), unlike C, an array of char is not a String, and neither a String nor an array of char is terminated by '\u0000' (the NUL character).

Try using `Message.trim()` to trim off white spaces.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I guess the problem was that I originally allocated 100 bytes for the receiving packet byte[] data = new byte[ 100 ]; I guess it took the reminder unused bytes and turn them into white spaces, thanks.